# Testng XML Groups Execution order

Tags: testng, execution

I have testng.xml file as below:

```
    <groups>
        <run>
            <include name="A" />
            <include name="B" />
            <include name="C" />
            <include name="D" />
```

And when I execute the xml file, which group among the above will be picked up first for execution? And suppose if I want say group  to executed at first always, Do we have an option for that?

Answer (score 0):

If it is not working out of the box, you can change the order with [a method interceptor](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#methodinterceptors).